# Disable or enable buttons if input condition met in JS, While input is auto-generated

Tags: javascript

i'm newbie in JS.
as in the title, I want to create a disable button when the condition is met based on the following code:

```
<input class="input" type="text">
<button class="button">Click Me</button>

<script>
let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let button = document.querySelector(".button");
button.disabled = true;
input.addEventListener("change", stateHandle);
function stateHandle() {
    if(document.querySelector(".input").value === "") {
        button.disabled = true;
    } else {
        button.disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

value on input is auto generated after 500ms. the code above works if after the input value appears and then I enter any number. what I want is when the input value appears then the button will automatically be in the enable position.

Comment: How does the value change; your function is reacting to the `change` event, which isn't fired when the value is changed by JavaScript. If you trigger a `change` event explicitly (with [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)) after the value has been updated, then it should work.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Thank you so much, it's works as i intended.

Comment: You're very welcome, may I ask that you edit your question to provide enough code to reproduce/demonstrate your problem, and then post an answer? That way your question is answered and of she use to future visitors?

Comment: yes, i'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @David's answer, I added new Events and dispatch them later.
This is the updated code :

```
<script >

    let input = document.querySelector("#input");
    let button = document.querySelector("#button");

    button.disabled = true; //setting button state to disabled
    
    const event = new Event("change"); //adding new event
    input.addEventListener("change", stateHandle);

    function stateHandle() {
        var t = document.getElementById("jarak").value,
        check = "luar";
        if (new RegExp('\\b' + check + '\\b').test(t)) {
        button.disabled = true; //button remains disabled
        } else {
        button.disabled = false; //button is enabled
        }
    }
setTimeout(function() {
    input.dispatchEvent(event); //dispatching event after 700ms
}, 700);
</script>
```